# Проблема с imageview и textview в Toolbar

Tags: android

У меня есть ImageView и TextView в Toolbar.Я поставил ImageView background-ом  TextView.Мне нужно поместить TextView в центр ImageView как на первой картинке[image: Я хочу сделать так]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается вот так

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/howManyitems"
            android:background="@drawable/logo2"
            android:textColor="@color/error_color"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: У TextView параметр android:gravity="center" не помогает?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У TextView добавьте параметр android:gravity="center"